# Counterexample to: If $|f''(x)|\leq m$, then $|f''(0)|+|f''(a)|\leq am$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples

[image: Original Question]

**Attempt towards a counter-example:**

Consider $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=-(x-\frac{1}{2})^4$.

$f$ takes its largest value at $x=0.5 \in  [0,1]^o$, i.e. the interior of $[0,1]$.

$f''(x)=-12(x-\frac{1}{2})^2$, and $|f''(x)|\leq 3$, $\forall x \in [0,1]$.

Now, $|f''(0)|=|f''(1)|=3$. Now, $|f''(0)|+|f''(1)|=6\nleq3$

Does this example work?

Kindly **VERIFY**

Comment: Could that be a typo in the book, and you actually have to show that $|f'(0)|+|f’(a)|\leq am$?

Comment: @MartinR That's what I thought. Is the example correct though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counterexample is correct. The statement is (trivially) correct if $a \ge 2$ and wrong if $a < 2$. As a counterexample one can choose any twice-differentiable function $f: [0, a] \to \Bbb R$ which has a maximum in the interior of the interval and where $f''$ attains its maximum both at $x=0$ and $x=a$. So another choice would be $f(x) = -(x-a/2)^2$.

On the other hand, one can prove that $|f'(0)|+|f’(a)|\leq am$, using the fact that $f'(c) = 0$ at the point $c$ where $f$ attains its maximum.